# How to display ImageView as a different size in program?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, resize, imageview

I tried searching but I don't seem to be able to find something easy enough for a beginner like myself.

If I have `ImageView` with a source file of 200px * 200px, and I want adjust it in the program to different sizes from time to time, let's say, to 400px * 400px. Is it possible?

I have tried something like these and I am not able to get it work:

```
iv.getLayoutParams().height = 400;
iv.getLayoutParams().width = 400;
```

this still displays my `ImageView` image the same size on the screen...

I also tried

```
iv.setMaximumHeight(400);
iv.setMaximumWidth(400);
```

it does not work for me either..

I am trying to write this with Eclipse, with java.

Comment: what language? That should be in the tags the ones you have are not helpful

Comment: Is this Android? If so you really need to specify that in the tags so someone who understands Android is more likely to see it.

Comment: thank you for suggestion, I will add tag android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

once you do

```
LayoutParams lp = iv.getLayoutParams();
lp.height = 400;
lp.width = 400;
```

you need to reset the layout params

```
iv.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind respond ^ ^